# Как можно задать Checked нескольким значениям на сайте? Или альтернатива для radio

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/use_your_illusion.png);
  color: #eee;
  font: 1em 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
  background-color: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabbed {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.tabbed > input {
  display: none;
}

.tabbed > label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.tabbed > label:hover,
.tabbed > input:checked + label {
  background: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabbed1 {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 500px auto;
}

.tabbed1 > input {
  display: none;
}

.tabbed1 > label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.tabbed1 > label:hover,
.tabbed1 > input:checked + label {
  background: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabs {
  clear: both;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.tabs > div {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 10px 30px 40px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: opacity .3s, transform 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4){
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="CSS Tabs" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.0.1/normalize.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>CSS Tabs</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tabbed">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-2">
    <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-3">
    <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-4">
    <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div><h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p></div>
      <div><h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabbed1">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-6" checked>
    <label for="tab-nav-6">HTML</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-2">
    <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-3">
    <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-nav-4">
    <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div><h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p></div>
      <div><h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.6/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Добрый день , подскажите пожалуйста, как задать checked каждому отдельному новому элементу на сайте, то есть есть сайт, на нем есть слайдер, в этом слайдере на каждом слайде есть табы, соответственно первый таб постоянно открыт с помощью **checked**, но только вот проблема в том, что при использовании того же checked на другом слайде, с первого он пропадает и встает на место второго. Как это можно обойти ?

**Или как можно для других элементов, кому тоже нужно прописать checked задать какую - то альтернативу выполняющую ту же функцию**

Comment: Давайте пример, тяжеловато понять то, что вы написали.

Comment: checked для нескольких radio нельзя, только checkbox.

Comment: А есть альтернатива checked ?

Comment: альтернатива - псевдокласс :target

Comment: спасибо !  это точно моя ошибка, если бы сам внимательно посмотрел на инпуты, то не пришлось бы никого отвлекать, спасибо еще раз за разъяснение

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот как-то так:
Вам просто нужно было группе `input type=radio` дать разные имена и плюс нужно в было в css еще кое что подшаманить все стало на место.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/use_your_illusion.png);
  color: #eee;
  font: 1em 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

::selection {
  background-color: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabbed {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.tabbed > input {
  display: none;
}

.tabbed > label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.tabbed > label:hover,
.tabbed > input:checked + label {
  background: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabbed1 {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 500px auto;
}

.tabbed1 > input {
  display: none;
}

.tabbed1 > label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.tabbed1 > label:hover,
.tabbed1 > input:checked + label {
  background: #4EC6DE;
}

.tabs {
  clear: both;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.tabs > div {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 10px 30px 40px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: opacity .3s, transform 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

#tab-nav-1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4),
#tab-nav-5:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tab-nav-6:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tab-nav-7:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tab-nav-8:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4){
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="CSS Tabs" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.0.1/normalize.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>CSS Tabs</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tabbed">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_1" id="tab-nav-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-nav-1">HTML</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_1" id="tab-nav-2">
    <label for="tab-nav-2">CSS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_1" id="tab-nav-3">
    <label for="tab-nav-3">Javascript</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_1" id="tab-nav-4">
    <label for="tab-nav-4">Output</label>
    <div class="tabs tabs_1">
      <div><h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p></div>
      <div><h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabbed1">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_2" id="tab-nav-5">
    <label for="tab-nav-5">HTML</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_2" id="tab-nav-6" checked>
    <label for="tab-nav-6">CSS</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_2" id="tab-nav-7">
    <label for="tab-nav-7">Javascript</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs_2" id="tab-nav-8">
    <label for="tab-nav-8">Output</label>
    <div class="tabs tabs_2">
      <div><h2>HTML</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. </p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nulla tortor, a posuere urna. Praesent urna quam, semper ut ultricies et, mollis ac elit. Suspendisse tempor, lacus id consectetur sagittis, lorem odio dignissim nulla, a condimentum sem neque sed ligula. Maecenas id risus eros, eget porttitor metus. Quisque pellentesque neque dignissim nisl pellentesque vitae tempus urna eleifend. Nullam egestas, neque id placerat luctus, nibh velit pharetra nulla, vel pretium justo massa ut elit. Vivamus nec auctor nunc.</p></div>
      <div><h2>CSS</h2><p>Maecenas dictum, urna ut consequat condimentum, est dui commodo diam, ac pretium dui ante eu quam. Curabitur posuere metus nec tellus venenatis placerat. Ut egestas neque in odio vulputate gravida. In at justo ac est laoreet eleifend vel quis arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae vehicula neque. Nam tempus erat ac ante tincidunt tincidunt. Pellentesque eu nibh sapien. Nunc augue magna, lacinia eget congue eget, mattis id tortor. Fusce id vestibulum neque. Proin tincidunt tellus ut risus lobortis cursus. Duis sit amet urna vel sapien ullamcorper varius.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Javascript</h2><p>Duis luctus dolor ac erat luctus hendrerit. Aenean id congue magna. Proin sit amet elit vel lacus ornare dignissim imperdiet nec odio. Maecenas condimentum egestas lorem et laoreet. Donec ut leo non purus rutrum euismod vel faucibus nunc. Curabitur vel mauris nisi, vitae laoreet erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas ipsum odio, iaculis id vulputate vitae, vestibulum at nunc. Integer non nisl lorem. Quisque lobortis congue semper. Nunc neque nisi, consequat id egestas vitae, porta vel sem.</p></div>
      <div><h2>Output</h2><p>Fusce vel eros eu lectus ultricies fermentum vestibulum adipiscing odio. Suspendisse ultricies, metus nec dapibus pharetra, quam arcu vulputate nisl, a pretium nisi velit id ante. Nunc auctor augue sit amet orci vestibulum id placerat nulla pellentesque. Duis vel quam velit. Ut auctor ipsum quis lacus semper non pretium mi dignissim. Morbi ultrices augue eget nisi hendrerit placerat. Mauris rhoncus urna quis metus congue quis condimentum risus interdum. Nam lobortis lectus et enim laoreet mattis. Integer faucibus ullamcorper erat, at rhoncus leo bibendum sed. Mauris libero urna, placerat non pretium ac, elementum et arcu. Aliquam non tellus diam, vel scelerisque odio. Etiam a quam et enim vehicula feugiat posuere at dui. Phasellus at nisl quam. Integer nisi mi, varius vitae placerat viverra, dapibus vitae massa. Nullam ut orci vitae nisi ornare aliquam in eget orci.</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.6/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```